# mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50531 Library:50613

Tags: php, mysql, header, mismatch

I'm really stuck trying to fix these errors on debian wheezy.

> mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50531 Library:50613 core.php on line 317

The problem occured today quite a while after an upgrade to php 5.4, ioncube loaders 4.4.3, xcache 3.0.3 and percona 5.6.

So far in my attempts to fix the problem I've tried...

1. Uninstalling php (including purging the install files)
2. Downgrading to php 5.3 then upgrading back
3. Downgrading back to percona 5.5 and upgrading back
4. Unloading ioncube headers
5. Unloading xcache

None of which has helped unfortunately...

### --

Line 317 starts with:

```
 $link = $this->
```

```
  /**
    * Initialize database connection(s)
    *
    * Connects to the specified master database server, and also to the slave server if it is specified
    *
    * @param        string  Name of the database server - should be either 'localhost' or an IP address
    * @param        integer Port of the database server (usually 3306)
    * @param        string  Username to connect to the database server
    * @param        string  Password associated with the username for the database server
    * @param        boolean Whether or not to use persistent connections to the database server
    * @param        string  Not applicable; config file for MySQLi only
    * @param        string  Force connection character set (to prevent collation errors)
    *
    * @return       boolean
    */
    function db_connect($servername, $port, $username, $password, $usepconnect, $configfile = '', $charset = '')
    {
            if (function_exists('catch_db_error'))
            {
                    set_error_handler('catch_db_error');
            }

            // catch_db_error will handle exiting, no infinite loop here
            do
            {
                    $link = $this->functions[$usepconnect ? 'pconnect' : 'connect']("$servername:$port", $username, $password);
            }
            while ($link == false AND $this->reporterror);

            restore_error_handler();

            if (!empty($charset))
            {
                    if (function_exists('mysql_set_charset'))
                    {
                            mysql_set_charset($charset);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $this->sql = "SET NAMES $charset";
                            $this->execute_query(true, $link);
                    }
            }

            return $link;
    }
```

Comment: Don't suppose we could see the code (perhaps around line 317) that might help?

Comment: you __should not__ use `mysql_*` to start with. that error is a blessig in disguise.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue when i recently upgrade my ubuntu server to 13.04 anyway this is just a warning from `libmysqlclient` i also have mariadb , you can use `php5-mysqlnd` instead of `php5-mysql` this fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql

sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.

Comment: This made phpMyAdmin not work :( it doesn't seem to support mysqlnd.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by aptitude purging on php 5.4 and php 5.3 and reinstalling php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for Percona 5.5 on Centos 6 after the above step did not help.

I am using Percona 5.5 Server, Client, and Devel packages. I ended up having to run the following to get my PHP compile to work (after removing Percona-shared-compat-5.1):

```
cp /usr/lib64/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client.so.18.0.0
cp /usr/lib64/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client.so
cp /usr/lib64/mysql/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client_r.a
cp /usr/lib64/mysql/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client.a
cp /usr/lib64/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client_r.so.18.0.0
cp /usr/lib64/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client_r.so
cp /usr/lib64/lib{perconaserver,mysql}client_r.so.18
```

I hope this helps anyone else trying to compile PHP from source when using Percona.